# How to determine the boot order of auto-starting apps?

Tags: boot, xposed-framework

Some apps boot and run in the background when an Android phone boots. WeChat is one example. It starts automatically so that the user can receive messages in real time. My question is how to view and change the boot order of all auto-starting apps. Or else is it random?

The motivation for asking is that I installed Xposed and wanted to change some information of my phone. But unfortunately WeChat sometimes boots before Xposed and thus bypasses the Xposed hooks. I tried very hard to solve this, but to no avail. So any suggestions?

Comment: If Xposed is installed then the initial Dalvik VM instance "Zygote" is altered in the boot process. Every app that is started forks the Zygote process and thus includes Xposed. This is my understanding of how Xposed works. Therefore it should be impossible for an app to start before Xposed. May be this is a timing problem in the boot process? What device do you use and how have you installed Xposed?

Comment: Andoid fires `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast once `system_server` is fully up on boot. Any app with `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` can receive the broadcast and start a service or whatever. There's no boot order that Android defines. // As Robert said, Xposed replaces core framework libraries in `/system`. So whenever `zygote` forks an app, it's loaded with modded libraries.

Comment: The only exception is that if you are using Magisk to bind mount Xposed modded files (and not actually replacing them in filesystem) and bind mount is delayed on boot so that an app is started before that. But this should not happen technically since Magisk is loaded very early in boot process.

Answer (score 0):

you can exec ps -A | grep com.tencent.mm, pid is start order
but Wechat isnot impossible to boot up before Xposed