# How to give an APK higher boot priority?

Tags: root-access, boot, xposed-framework, greenify, lsposed

I have a KernelSU rooted & Xposed/LSPosed enabled Android device running Android 10.

Greenify by Oasis APK can detect what receiver trigger the startup of an APK, but when Greenify boot late, it won't know that.

I want to give Greenify a higher boot priority to detect those other startup APKs receivers or providers or services (Not the traditional BOOT_COMPLETED receiver as it comes late), I tried making Greenify a System APK and device admin, but still its boot priority is low, I tried modifiying packages.xml in /data/system but no luck.

I created this script in KernelSU service.d folder but I think the device is overwhelmed by the receivers at the boot process

```
#!/system/bin/sh

wait_for_process() {
    while [ ! -e "/proc/$1" ]; do
        sleep 1
    done
}

wait_for_process $(pidof com.android.systemui)

# Trigger Startup for Greenify
am broadcast -n com.oasisfeng.greenify/.Startup
```

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [How to determine the boot order of auto-starting apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234313/44325)

Comment: I think its about development and thus off-topic.